# using pipe delimited string in URL in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pass a pipe delimited string as a parameter in my url in django, but it fails to route to the respective view.

This is my pipe delimited string:

> "main/1|adel|1|1989-09-19|1|1|test alert|2018-03-16-09-26-00|test module|1|1|test encounter"

and this is my url pattern:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from alerter import views

app_name = 'alerter'

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^main/(?P<message>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$',
    views.TheView.as_view({'get': 'view'}), name = 'main'),



]
```

Comment: your regex trying to look for `words` while you are passing words and special characters...

Comment: one of the possible solution is replace `\w+` with `\S+` . or pass the message as url parameter

Comment: I believe `\S+` will capture `/` in the URL, but yes, the solution is to use an appropriate regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`\w` doesn't match `|`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> For Unicode (str) patterns:
>
> Matches Unicode word characters; this includes most characters that can be part of a word in any language, as well as numbers and the underscore. If the [`ASCII`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.ASCII) flag is used, only `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is matched (but the flag affects the entire regular expression, so in such cases using an explicit `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` may be a better choice).

Adjust your pattern, e.g. by capturing `[a-zA-Z0-9_|]`:

```
url(r'^main/(?P<message>[a-zA-Z0-9_|]+)/$',
    views.TheView.as_view({'get': 'view'}), name='main')
```

Comment: although i'm convinced it should work, it didn't, the url works if i used non delimited string but even if i used a hyphen as delimiter, it fails.

Comment: I frequently use hyphens in URLs. Maybe another rule is matching your URLs. What does "it fails" mean? Do you get a 404, or does a different view load? Please edit your question and add your whole `urls.py` file.

Comment: i get a 404, will add my full file now

Comment: @adelelsayed, you don't appear to have included `|` (or `-`, for that matter) in your regular expression. Take a close look at mine: I added `|` after `_`. (The hyphens in this expression are used to indicate ranges, not as literal hyphens.)

Comment: i just forgot to write it here in stakoverflow, i included "- and space" to my regex, it turned out that i forgot about them.
    url(r'^main/(?P<message>[ a-zA-Z0-9_|-]+)/$',
    views.TheView.as_view({'get': 'view'}), name = 'main')